# I'm trying to write software that converts ASCII to decimal, adds to it, and converts back to ASCII

Tags: c++, encryption, software-design

I am having trouble with my code. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char word[128];
    int x = 0;
    int v;
    int shift;
    int sv;
    cin >> shift;
    cin >> word;

    while (word[x] != '\0')    // While the string isn't at the end... 
    {
        cout << int(word[x]) << " ";    // Transform the char to int
        x++;

        v = int(word[x]);
        sv = v + shift;

        cout << sv;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a Caesar cipher, well at least a part of it.

When I input:

```
shift=1
word=f
```

I expect the result to be:

```
102 103
```

Instead, I end up with this:

```
102 1
```

What am I doing wrong? is there a better way?

Comment: you displayed `word[x]` but right after it, you incremented `x`, and then shifting `word[x]`.  The `word[x]` you are shifting is already next char (NULL in your example) as `x` has been incremented.   Learn to use a for each loop, or at least write a proper `for` loop.  So something like `for (x = 0; word[x] != 0; ++x) { cout << word[x]; shiftedVal = word[x] + shift; cout << shiftedVal; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line that increments `x` at the end of the loop. You are incrementing `x` before displaying the shifted value.

```
while (word[x] != '\0')    // While the string isn't at the end... 
{
    cout << int(word[x]) << " ";    // Transform the char to int

    v = int(word[x]);
    sv = v + shift;

    cout << sv;
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now i can work on the other aspects of the code

Answer (score 0):

Loop counters  are usually incremented at the end of the loop after all the processing is done. In your case `x` acts as a loop counter as it is determining the condition of the `while` loop.

So the statement `x++` should come after all the processing, i.e. after the last `cout`.

In case of a [for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for),

> the `iteration_expression`  is executed **after** every iteration of the loop and **before** re-evaluating condition. Typically, **this is the expression that increments the loop counter**.

So you can change the above `while` to `for` like this:

```
for(x = 0; word[x] != '\0'; x++)
```

Then you **do not** have to increment `x` inside the loop.